Change formatting of author names to 'Lastname, FM'
I'm using the apalike bibliography style, and I would like to turn
Bolger, A. M., Lohse, M., and Usadel, B. (2014). Trimmomatic: a flexible trimmer
for Illumina sequence data. Bioinformatics, 30(15):2114–2120.

into
Bolger AM, Lohse M, and Usadel B (2014). Trimmomatic: a flexible trimmer
for Illumina sequence data. Bioinformatics, 30(15):2114–2120.

Any ideas how to do this?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

I suggest you perform the following series of steps:

Find the file apalike.bst in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, apalike-nodots.bst. (Don’t edit an original TeX distribution file directly.)

Open the file apalike-nodots.bst in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.

In the file apalike-nodots.bst, search for the format.names BibTeX function. (In my copy of this file, the function starts on line 209.)

About six lines down from the FUNCTION {format.names} line, you should find the following line:
  { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't :=   % last name first


In this line, change {, f.} to {, f{}}. Even if you're not familiar with BibTeX's programming interface and language, I trust you can figure out that f. means "first name truncated, followed by a period" (aka "full stop"), while f{} means "first name truncated, not followed by a period.

Save the newly-modified file apalike-nodots.bst either in the directory that contains the tex file(s) you're working on or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. (If you have no idea what the preceding sentence means, I suggest you choose the former option...)

In your main tex file, change
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

to
\bibliographystyle{apalike-nodots}

Then, perform a full recompile cycle on your document: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate the changes.


Happy BibTeXing!
